Bot stops running after authorizing it
I’m making a comment bot to raise awareness about conversion therapy and why it’s bad, but there's a weird bug I need help solving.
After I followed a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6FNWI9z_5J4), it seemed to work, but after I run it and log in to my email, the program just stops and doesn't do what I wanted it to do (comment on videos) Do you know how to fix this?
I don't really know how this works but I'm guessing it has to do with this:
with open(r'/Users/carte/OneDrive/Desktop/YouTube-Bot-master1/data/comments.txt') as f:
    foo = [line.strip() for line in f]
    print ('poopoo')


# keyword
with open(r'/Users/carte/OneDrive/Desktop/YouTube-Bot-master1/data/keywords.txt') as f:
    foooo = [line.strip() for line in f]
    print ('peepee')


keywords = open(r'/Users/carte/OneDrive/Desktop/YouTube-Bot-master1/data/keywords.txt')
x = 10
while x < 20:
    for line in keywords:
        scrape(line)
        print ('butt')


        with open(r'/Users/carte/OneDrive/Desktop/YouTube-Bot-master1/data/keywords.txt') as f:
            print ('puke')
            f.readline()
            data = f.read()
            f.seek(0)
            f.write(data)
            f.truncate()
            print ('poo')


            try:
                with open(r'/Users/carte/OneDrive/Desktop/YouTube-Bot-master1/data/keywords.txt') as f:
                    urls = []
                    for url in f:
                        rand = random.choice(foo)
                        print ('puke')


                        comment_threads_insert(client,
                        {'snippet.channelId': 'UCNlM-pgjmd0NNE5I6MzlEGg',
                         'snippet.videoId': url,
                         'snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.textOriginal': rand},
                        part='snippet')
                        print ('fart')
            except:
                pass
            print("Searching for video based in your keywords...")




I put a print statement in all the functions to see if they ran, and all of them did up to that point. I don't really know what to do other than this. This is all brand new to me.
Also people said I didn't provide enough code, and I don't really know where to stop so here's the entire thing:
import os import google.oauth2.credentials
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import random 
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow 
from googleapiclient.discovery import build 
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError 
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow


CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "\\Users\\carte\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\YouTube-Bot-master1\\client_secret.json"


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl'] API_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtube' API_VERSION = 'v3'

def get_authenticated_service():   flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES) credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=0)   return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials = credentials)


def print_response(response):   print ('0')   print(response)

def build_resource(properties):   resource = {}   for p in properties:
    prop_array = p.split('.')
    ref = resource
    for pa in range(0, len(prop_array)):
      is_array = False
      key = prop_array[pa]


      if key[-2:] == '[]':
        key = key[0:len(key)-2:]
        is_array = True


      if pa == (len(prop_array) - 1):
        if properties[p]:
          if is_array:
            ref[key] = properties[p].split(',')
          else:
            ref[key] = properties[p]
      elif key not in ref:
        ref[key] = {}
        ref = ref[key]
      else:
        ref = ref[key]   return resource


def remove_empty_kwargs(**kwargs):   good_kwargs = {}   if kwargs is not None:
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
      if value:
        good_kwargs[key] = value   return good_kwargs


def comment_threads_insert(client, properties, **kwargs):   resource = build_resource(properties)


  kwargs = remove_empty_kwargs(**kwargs)


  response = client.commentThreads().insert(
    body=resource,
    **kwargs   ).execute()


  return print_response(response)


def scrape(keyword):
    url = 'https://www.youtube.com/results?q={}&sp=CAISAggBUBQ%253D'.format(keyword)
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
    f = open('/Users/carte/OneDrive/Desktop/YouTube-Bot-master1/data/keywords.txt', 'w')
    for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'yt-uix-tile-link'}):
        href = link.get('href')
        newhref = href.replace("/watch?v=", "")
        f.write(newhref + '\n')



if __name__ == '__main__':   os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'   client = get_authenticated_service()

with open(r'/Users/carte/OneDrive/Desktop/YouTube-Bot-master1/data/comments.txt') as f:
    foo = [line.strip() for line in f]
    print ('poopoo')


# keyword
with open(r'/Users/carte/OneDrive/Desktop/YouTube-Bot-master1/data/keywords.txt') as f:
    foooo = [line.strip() for line in f]
    print ('peepee')


keywords = open(r'/Users/carte/OneDrive/Desktop/YouTube-Bot-master1/data/keywords.txt')
x = 10
while x < 20:
    for line in keywords:
        scrape(line)
        print ('butt')


        with open(r'/Users/carte/OneDrive/Desktop/YouTube-Bot-master1/data/keywords.txt') as f:
            print ('puke')
            f.readline()
            data = f.read()
            f.seek(0)
            f.write(data)
            f.truncate()
            print ('poo')


            try:
                with open(r'/Users/carte/OneDrive/Desktop/YouTube-Bot-master1/data/keywords.txt') as f:
                    urls = []
                    for url in f:
                        rand = random.choice(foo)
                        print ('puke')


                        comment_threads_insert(client,
                        {'snippet.channelId': 'UCNlM-pgjmd0NNE5I6MzlEGg',
                         'snippet.videoId': url,
                         'snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.textOriginal': rand},
                        part='snippet')
                        print ('fart')
            except:
                pass
            print("Searching for video based in your keywords...")


Without the rest of the code included in your post, it's hard to tell what's going wrong.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

where did it stop please ?

@D.L it prints the first 2 things, but not anything after the while x < 20 part.

maybe use more print() and display what you have in variables.

the biggest mistake except: pass - you may have error in code but you can't see it because you use pass. You should at least display it except Exception as ex: print(ex). OR for test you should remove try/except to see full error messages.

@furas is correct. At the very least do that. Furthermore in practice one should know the expected error and specifically catch those.

@furas where is try/except? I don't see that anywhere. Are you talking about try:
with open(r'/Users/carte/OneDrive/Desktop/YouTube-Bot-master1/data/keywords.txt') as f:
urls = []
for url in f:
rand = random.choice(foo)
print ('puke')

@furas how do i do that?

yes I'm talking about try open ... except: pass - especially about except: pass. "how do i do that?"simply delete linetry:, and delete lines except: pass, and correct indentations - and run code to see full error messages. And when you get error then use it's type to create better except - like except FileNotFoundError as ex: print(ex)`
